# Group a dataframe by some cols but keeping another ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like this :

```
 data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Tom', 'Nick'],
        'Last Name':['Holland', 'Jonas', 'Holland', 'Jonas'],
        'Year':[2020, 2019, 2019, 2020],
        'Payment': [12345, 12345, 32451,91782]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

|  | Name | Last Name | Year | Payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tom | Holland | 2020 | 12345 |
| 1 | Nick | Jonas | 2019 | 12345 |
| 2 | Tom | Holland | 2019 | 32451 |
| 3 | Nick | Jonas | 2020 | 91782 |

And I want to group the data according to the first and last name, but keeping the other columns, like this :

| Name | Last Name | Year | Payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Holland | 2020 | 12345 |
|  |  | 2019 | 32451 |
| Nick | Jonas | 2019 | 12345 |
|  |  | 2020 | 91782 |

I was trying

```
cols = ['Year','Payment']
df = df[cols].groupby(df_funpub_2[['Last Name', 'Name']])
```

but i get the following error

> ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional

Comment: why is Tom Holland's year in descending order but Nick Jonas' is in ascending order?

Comment: It is an example, but the date data is out of order

Comment: I think you're looking to sort index but the date is not sorted so not sure what the expected output is. Try: `df.set_index(['Name','Last Name', 'Year']).sort_index()`

Answer (score 2):

I assume the `Year` column is unique for each group so this should work:

`df.groupby(['Name', 'Last Name']).agg({'Year': 'last', 'Payment': 'sum'})`

Otherwise, you might want to include `Year` as a group.

**EDIT**

To achieve your desired outcome, `Year` must be included as a group so:

`df.groupby(['Name', 'Last Name', 'Year']).agg({'Payment': 'sum'})`